# Can't find dev_appserver.py with gcloud installation

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-app-engine-python

I've installed gcloud by following the instructions on:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu

`gcloud` is in my path at `/usr/bin/gcloud`, but the package doesn't seem to have `dev_appserver.py` in my path. Is it installed? How do I run it?

Platform: Ubuntu 16.04

Edit: By running `dpkg -L google-cloud-sdk` I've found it at `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py` but when I try to run it I get:

`This action requires the installation of components: [app-engine-
python]
You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is 
managed by an external package manager.  If you would like to get the`

Also not sure why it wasn't added to my path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `google-cloud-sdk` deb package comes with the [built-in component manager](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/managing-components) disabled, which is preventing that copy of dev_appserver.py from working through gcloud. If you update your apt-cache, you can install the `google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python` and/or `google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java` packages that have just started to be published. Directions here:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#apt-get

Comment: Ok, thanks. I solved it by installing manually rather than through packages. Perhaps someday I'll go back to the new packages. Thanks!

Comment: This is linux specific. How about OSX? Thx

Comment: On Mac, you should use `gcloud components install app-engine-python` in order to get dev_appserver.py with your Cloud SDK installation.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I installed the cloud-sdk as a deb. package. The regular /usr/bin/dev_appserver.py does not work, however, I found one at "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" that is working.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Worked for me:
`sudo apt install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python-extras`

Answer (score 11):

I know the original question concerns Ubuntu, but I just wanted to share some notes for macOS/OS X in case it's helpful for someone else.

I installed the `google-cloud-sdk` via [Homebrew-Cask](https://caskroom.github.io) and overlooked the [caveats note](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/google-cloud-sdk.rb#L20):

```
brew cask install google-cloud-sdk
```

After installing the SDK cask, I installed the Python App Engine component, as @Rodney Jonace mentioned:

```
gcloud components install -q app-engine-python
```

Going back to the caveats note mentioned above, I appended the following the my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
source $(brew --prefix)/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc
source $(brew --prefix)/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc
```

Opening a new terminal tab, I was able to call the extra Python App Engine scripts (e.g., `dev_appserver.py`) and use the Zsh completions. Hope that helps!

The following articles were also useful:

http://www.javatronic.fr/tips/2014/10/17/installing_google_cloud_sdk_on_ubuntu_with_oh-my-zsh.html

http://www.rainbowbreeze.it/how-to-setup-a-google-app-engine-python-environment-on-mac-osx-using-homebrew/